# Failed Assertion: boolean expression must not be null. Initially the loading screen is called

Tags: android, flutter

My code is as follows:

```js
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  List<CategoryModel> categories = new List<CategoryModel>();
  List<ArticleModel> articles = new List<ArticleModel>();
  bool _loading = true;

  getNews() async{
    News newsClass = News();
    await newsClass.getNews();
    articles = newsClass.news;
    setState(() {
      _loading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getNews();
    categories = getCategories();
    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("News"),
            Text("App", style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.blueAccent
            ),)
          ],
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),

      body: _loading ? Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ) : SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[

              /// Categories
              Container(
                height: 70,
                child: ListView.builder(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    itemCount: categories.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index){
                      return CategoryTile(
                        imageUrl: categories[index].imageUrl,
                        categoryName: categories[index].categoryName,
                      );
                    }),
              ),

              /// Blog
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: articles.length,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index){
                      return BlogTile(
                        imageUrl: articles[index].urlToImage,
                        title: articles[index].title,
                        desc: articles[index].description,
                      );
                    }),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CategoryTile extends StatelessWidget {

  final imageUrl, categoryName;
  CategoryTile({this.imageUrl, this.categoryName});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: (){

      },
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 16),
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                child: CachedNetworkImage(
                  imageUrl: imageUrl, width: 120, height: 60, fit: BoxFit.cover,)
            ),
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              width: 120, height: 60,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                color: Colors.black26,
              ),
              child: Text(categoryName, style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 14,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500
              ),),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BlogTile extends StatelessWidget {

  final String imageUrl, title, desc;
  BlogTile({@required this.imageUrl,@required this.title,@required this.desc});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
              child: Image.network(imageUrl)
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 8,),
          Text(title, style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 17, color: Colors.black87, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500
          ),),
          SizedBox(height: 8,),
          Text(desc, style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black54
          ),)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When I run the code it shows the loading screen which is not going off, the content which i want to display is not showing. Please help by providing your valuable answer. Thank you in advance.

The error I am getting is as follows:

E/flutter ( 5339): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null

Answer (score 0):

Since you are initialising your `_loading` variable inside the first statement of the `initState`. You can as well initialise it directly when declaring it.

Like this:
`bool _loading = true;`

Try the code below:

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  List<CategoryModel> categories = new List<CategoryModel>();
  List<ArticleModel> articles = new List<ArticleModel>();
  bool _loading = true;

  getNews() async{
    News newsClass = News();
    await newsClass.getNews();
    articles = newsClass.news;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getNews();
    categories = getCategories();
    setState(() {
      _loading = false;
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I tried it but it is not working , only loading screen is showing up and not the content screen.

Comment: Post the code where you have the ```News``` class and where you are displaying the ```content``` screen @InsaneBeast

Comment: Check my updated answer @InsaneBeast. Let's see if that works

Comment: It is somewhat working only categories are showing up and not the articles. @T.T Sage

Comment: Can you move this discussion to the room ? @InsaneBeast. So I can explain properly there.

Comment: Can you tell how to move discussion to the room? @T.T Sage

Comment: I have no idea too. Let's continue using the comment section till it automatically suggests we move to room.

Comment: Can you post your ```NewClass``` ???? and ```getCategories``` fuunction?? @InsaneBeast